# Replace a line with the line that I have in the buffer in vi

Tags: vi, replace

I `cc` or `dd` to copy a line into my paste buffer. Then I go to a new location.

I want to replace a line that I see. So I type `p` <kbd>Down</kbd> `dd`.

Is there an easier way (fewer keystrokes)?

Comment: Hmm, for one off edits, that's how I usually do it.  I'd be interested in any shorter way as well.

Comment: You can type `V` to select the line, then `p` to replace it.

Comment: @angus, turn that comment into an answer!  It's a good answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can type `V` to select the line, then `p` to replace it.

Comment: I think this is the only anwer I've seen that actually has less keystrokes than `dd`, move, `pjdd`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this would be `"_ddp`

`"_dd` deletes the current line to the null-buffer. This doesn't over write what you had just copied, which I have found helpful a lot of times! The `p` pastes the line you had copied earlier.

Might not be shorter in terms of keystrokes, but knowing this is an option can be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Angus and Thor have the short answers covered, so here's some bonus exploration.

If for some reason you want to delete before pasting, you can take advantage of the numbered registers.  The `"0` register contains the text yanked by the last `y` or `Y`, but not delete.  The `"1` through `"9` registers store the last 9 deletes/cuts you've done.  So:

- If you yanked with `yy`, you could replace with `dd"0P`.
- If you cut with `dd` or `cc`, you could replace with `dd"2P`.  (Not `dd"1P` because the `dd` fills `"1`.)

Try `:help "0` for more in-depth info.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to replace line 1 by 3 than you could do `:1m3|2d`

This effectively moves line 1 to line 3, and removes line 2 (i.e. the old line 3)